# Error while deploying NextJS app to AWS with serverless framework

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, next.js, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

When I tried to deploy my NextJS app to AWS with serverless framework.

In my next JS app directory, I ran the command `npx serverless`

and got the following error -

```
$ npx serverless

  error:
  Error: Command failed with ENOENT: node_modules/.bin/next build
spawn node_modules/.bin/next ENOENT
'node_modules\.bin\next' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\patel\.serverless\components\registry\npm\@sls-next\serverless-component@1.18.0\node_modules\@sls-next\serverless-component\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\patel\.serverless\components\registry\npm\@sls-next\serverless-component@1.18.0\node_modules\@sls-next\serverless-component\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\patel\.serverless\components\registry\npm\@sls-next\serverless-component@1.18.0\node_modules\@sls-next\serverless-component\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node_modules/.bin/next',
  path: 'node_modules/.bin/next',
  spawnargs: [ 'build' ],
  originalMessage: 'spawn node_modules/.bin/next ENOENT',
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with ENOENT: node_modules/.bin/next build\n' +
    'spawn node_modules/.bin/next ENOENT',
  command: 'node_modules/.bin/next build',
  exitCode: undefined,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: '',
  stderr: "'node_modules\\.bin\\next' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\n" +
    'operable program or batch file.',
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}

  3s » myNextApplication » Error: Command failed with ENOENT: node_modules/.bin/next build
spawn node_modules/.bin/next ENOENT
'node_modules\.bin\next' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm using `aws configure` to set my AWS credentials.

My `serverless.yml` file is as follow,

```
myNextApplication:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@1.18.0"
```

How should I deploy my app to AWS cloud with a serverless framework?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before running that command?

Comment: Yes, all the required modules are perfectly installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem is that I have the setup in a **monorepo** using **yarn workspaces** and **lerna**, and **next** was declared as a shared dependency in the root of the monorepo, and the nextjs app I was trying to deploy didn't have the dependency explicitly in its package.json.

For serverless to run, we need to have this dependency declared there as well.

in my case, I simply included:

```
"next": "11.1.3-canary.49",
```

in dependencies and now serverless is capable to run the command as well.